# Serverless Mailgun not generating mail

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless, mailgun

Thought I'd dip my toe into Serverless and see if I can generate a function to send a message via Mailgun. My function succesfully runs with the message "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!" but no message is sent via Mailgun:

My handler.js:

```
'use strict';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: 'xxx', domain: 'email.mydomain.co.uk'})

module.exports.hello = async event => {
        var data = {
            from: 'no-reply@email.mydomain.co.uk',
            to: 'me@somewhere.co.uk',
            subject: 'Hello',
            text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
        };

        mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
            if(error)
            {
                    console.log(error)
            }
            console.log(body);
        });

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify('Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!')
        };
};
```

My serverless.yml is very simple:

```
service: helloworld
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: eu-west-2
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: post
```

I've tested the function with curl and via the UI in AWS but neither provide any debug messages related to mailgun.

Comment: Since you are using [async handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async), don't you need to put everything in a `new Promise`?

Comment: @Marcin The `async` is for functions that also to use `await`. The OP is not doing that. In fact the `async` keyword us superfluous as long as the function returns a promise. And `mailgun-js` is already promise-based so there is no need to use `new Promise()`, either.

Comment: @Tomalak api is https://github.com/highlycaffeinated/mailgun-js rather than the one provided (and seemingly abandoned) by Mailgun. Still old but does work.

Comment: @Zakalwe always link to the libraries you use, it's not useful to keep people guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that, since the `.send()` method is asynchronous, your handler does not wait long enough and finishes running before the message is done.

Return a promise (the API of `mailgun-js` is already producing promises, you just need to return them):

```
module.exports.hello = event => {
    return mailgun.messages().send({
        from: 'no-reply@email.mydomain.co.uk',
        to: 'me@somewhere.co.uk',
        subject: 'Hello',
        text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
    }).then(msgBody => {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({status: 'sent a message!', text: msgBody})
    });
};
```

when you return an actual promise yourself, the `async` keyword becomes superfluous. You can rewrite the same thing in `async`/`await` style:

```
module.exports.hello = async event => {
    var msgBody = await mailgun.messages().send({
        from: 'no-reply@email.mydomain.co.uk',
        to: 'me@somewhere.co.uk',
        subject: 'Hello',
        text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
    });

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({status: 'sent a message!', text: msgBody})
    };
};
```

Comment: Sweet! I did wonder if the function had been terminating before completion. This helped. Thanks!

Comment: @Zakalwe If you use `async`, make sure you also use `await`. It's almost certainly an error if you don't.